# Optional parameter in ASP.net 4.0 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameter-passing

I have a website built in ASP.NET 4.0 and currently I have a drop down box with URLs, a button that goes to that URL and parses out text and then finally a results box with the parsed text.

What I want to do is instead of going to my website and choosing the URL in the drop down box, I want to pass on the parameter as a full URL and have the button go to that and then do its thing. Kind of like a permanent link that I can hand to a user

For instance:

http://localhost:62554/WebSite5/Default.aspx --> http://google.com

google.com gets put into a variable (lets say its `MyURL`) and the button takes it just like if it were in the drop down box.
**Updated code: Now getting a error 500 at

```
using (StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
```

---

```
string newURL;
String url;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //Request.Params.Get("newURL").ToString();
    //string url = Request["newURL"];
    //url = Request.QueryString["newURL"].ToString();
    url = Request.QueryString["newURL"].ToString();

    parseButton_Click(sender, e);
}
protected void parseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //MyURL = deviceCombo.Text;
    //MyURL = Request.Params.Get("");
    //MyURL = Request.Params.Get("newURL");
    //MyURL = newURL;
    //string MyURL = Request.Params["newURL"].ToString();

    WebRequest objRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    objRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    using (StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
    {
        originalText.Text = objReader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    //Read all lines of file
    String[] crString = { "<BR>&nbsp;" };
    String[] aLines = originalText.Text.Split(crString, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    String noHtml = String.Empty;

    for (int x = 0; x < aLines.Length; x++)
    {
        if (aLines[x].Contains(filterCombo.SelectedValue))
        {
            noHtml += (RemoveHTML(aLines[x]) + "\r\n");

        }
    }

    //Print results to textbox
    resultsBox.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, noHtml);
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Kind of like a permanent link that I can hand to a user instead of them going to my website and clicking the drop down box and selecting the correct URL to parse.

Comment: One note: Never test anything against google.  First, it's not nice.  Second, and more importantly, depending on how much testing you are doing, google may decide to block you.  I've seen it happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the URL variable from the Request object.

```
string url = Request["newURL"];
```

Put this wherever you like such as Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = Request["newURL"];
}
```

Comment: Can you post more of your code and the URL you are passing? This should work no problem, the issue must be elsewhere.

Comment: I updated the original question with my code, I get the url but it crashes at 'using (StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
'

Comment: I think calling a button event handler like that is a bad idea, your event handler should just get the URL and pass it to a function that does the work. Same as in page_load, you should get the URL from request params and then call the function.

Answer (score 3):

Your question was hard to understand, but I think what you are trying to do is pass in the website string in the URL. I think what you want to do is use URL params, so if they go to "http://localhost:62554/Website5/default.aspx?newURL=http://google.com" it acts as if they had chosen google.com in the dropdown.

Anything after the ? in the URL is treated as an URL param, you can access these params in the codebehind like this:

```
string newURL = Request.Params.Get("newURL");
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want to do but where do I put this code?

Comment: Put this code in the page_load section of your codebehind, make sure to wrap it in if (!IsPostBack) so that it will only happen the first time they hit the page.